# Как сохранить ModelForm?

Tags: django

[views.py](http://views.py)

```
if request.method=='POST':
    form=AddForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

[forms.py](http://forms.py)

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Post
    fields=('header','theme','preview','text')
    widgets={
        'header': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span17'}),
        'preview': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'span17'}),
        'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'span17'})
    }
```

[models.py](http://models.py)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    text=models.TextField(max_length=1000, verbose_name=u'Текст',)
    header=models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u'Заголовок')
    preview=models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Превью')
    pub_date=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    theme=models.ManyToManyField(PostTheme, verbose_name=u'Тема поста')

class Meta:
    ordering=['-id']

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.header
```

Не получается сохранить введенную форму. Как быть?

Comment: Вообще форма у вас называется `AddForm`, а `instance` используется для *Изменения* объекта. Да и как уже писали ниже там не юзер должен быть, а экземпляр `Post`

Comment: Изменил instance на Post: type object 'Post' has no attribute 'text'

Comment: `#Creating a form to change an existing article.
>>> article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> form = ArticleForm(instance=article)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотри ошибки, выведи на консоль:

```
print form.errors
```

сделай так:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    form=AddForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_post = form.save(commit=False)
        new_post.author = request.user
        new_post.save()
```

Comment: А в каком месте? Пробую сразу после form.save(), ничего не выводит

Comment: после блока if form.is_valid():

Comment: перед проверкой .is_valid()

Comment: Ни до, ни после ошибок не возвращает, только пустые строки

Comment: ну модель покажи что ли

Comment: Обновил топик. Вроде модель ничем не выделяющаяся

Comment: у тебя поле author обязательное

Comment: Ну да, автор же и есть request.user

Answer (score 2):

Странно, а почему instance=request.user, а model=Post?

Comment: Ну как же? Я пытаюсь создать пост. Следовательно модель нужна от Post, а вот насчет instance я не уверен

Comment: instance - экземпляр объекта используемой в форме модели. Т.е. если нужно в форме вывести данные из уже существующего объекта класса Post - то нужно передавать его в форму через параметр instance…

Comment: Подозреваю тоже самое. Если Форма модели `Post`, то и инстанс должен быть тоже Post. Все логично.

Пройдитесь дебагером - скорее всего форма просто невалидна. И в ветку if у вас скрипт просто не заходит.

Comment: А как мне тогда это дело организовать? Неправильный instance так влияет на сохранение?

Comment: Изменил instance на Post, вот такое выдает:

type object 'Post' has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Значит в модели Post нет поля text…

Comment: Вообще все проблемы от лени. Если бы не лень, то вы бы прочитали документацию (к слову сказать у Джанги она просто охуительная), и не возникало бы таких глупых вопросов. Смотрите ниже ответ - то, что вам нужно

Comment: Изменил instance на Post, вот такое выдает:
type object 'Post' has no attribute 'text'

Если вы написал instanse=Post. То так и будет писать. Надо туда **ЭКЗЕМПЛЯР** класса, а не класс

Comment: Если пост создаётся с нуля, то инстанс вообще передавать не надо! Иснтанс в данном контексте - редактируемый пост, а не создаваемый с нуля… Т.е. он уже был когда создан и сохранён…

Answer (score 0):

Вот как решил вопрос:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    form=AddForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post=form.save(commit=False)
        post.author=request.user
        post.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```